# webdriver-manager is not recognized as the name of a cmdlt

Tags: angular, protractor, automated-tests

When I set up a protractor test suite  I got this error in visual code terminal :

```
PS C:\Users\nga\Documents\GitHub\ASPIT\Timeline\protractor\exampleTypescript> webdriver-manager start
```

> webdriver-manager : The term 'webdriver-manager' is not recognized as
>   the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
>   the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + webdriver-manager start
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (webdriver-manager:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have `webdriver-manager` installed globally. That is why you are getting this message. You will need to install it globally or create a script in your package.json to run this command.

```
npm install -g webdriver-manager
```

If you only want it to be installed locally, add a script to your package.json

```
scripts: {
    "webdriver:start": "webdriver-manager start"
}
```

And then run the script from the command line

```
npm run webdriver:start
```

Comment: A note of caution for global installs: when using a global install of webdriver-manager and not local for  Protractor, direct connect and a local start of selenium server will not work.